# jQuery and the mouseover event

Tags: jquery, live, mouseover

I need to know how to fix this problem. I have a mouseleave event on my  list.

```
jQuery(".list").live("mouseleave", function(event) {

    alert("Boom");

});
```

But at the same time I have a tooltip displayed over it. This tooltip doesn't belong to this  list, it is in other div.

Now, when i move mouse over that div, i get an alert - i left the  list.

Please, tell me how i can do that when i move mouse in this tooltip, there will be no action.

I've tried this sentence, but it doesn't work:

```
if($(event.target).hasClass('name')) alert("D");
```

Comment: This is not a mouseover event but a mouseleave which are differents !

Comment: You should use `.on` instead of `.live`, as live has been deprecated

Comment: definitly `$(".list").on('mouseleave', [filter selector],function(event){});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `relatedTarget` property from the `mouseleave` event, this contains an object of the element which the mouse was over at the time the `mouseleave` event fired:

```
jQuery('.list').bind('mouseleave', function(event) {
  if(jQuery(event.relatedTarget).attr('id') != 'yourToolTipId') {
    alert("Boom");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a working solution to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SVzv5/8/

In this example the red square is your list and the blue square is your tooltip. Interact with them on jsfiddle to see them working.

Html code:

```
<div id="under"></div>
<div id="over"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#under').bind('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).css({background:'yellow'});
}).bind('mouseout', function () {
    $(this).css({background:'red'});
});
```

CSS code:

```
#under {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#over {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    background:blue;
    display:block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution, I didn't knew about CSS property pointer-events: none; so I've learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to execute your event handler with a small timeout and cancel it if the mouse enters your tooltip. It would be achieved the following way:

var timeout;

```
handler = function () { 
    // handler 
};

jQuery('.list').bind('mouseout', function (event) {
    timeout = setTimeout(handler, 250);
});

jQuery('#tooltipId').bind('mouseover', function (event) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```